# Building a flask + heroku app, s3 hosting for static assets (js and images currently not loading)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, heroku, flask, amazon-s3

I'm building a flask app called `Neuroethics_Behavioral_Task`.

I also have an s3 bucket called `neuroethics-task`. In the root directory, I uploaded a file called `experiment.js` and an image, `test.png`.

I followed the instructions in these two parts of Heroku's documentation about s3:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python

The first link says the following about how to access assets you've uploaded to s3

> After assets are uploaded, you can refer to their public URLs (such as http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/filename) in your application’s code. These files will now be served directly from S3, freeing up your application to serve only dynamic requests.

So I have this line in the header of one of the html templates.

`<script href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/neuroethics-task/experiment.js"></script>`

I also tried to include the image from copying the path directly on s3 (which is different from the heroku docs). Here's that line.

`<img src='s3://neuroethics-task/test.png'`

**The issue is that nothing happens when I access the web page that's supposed to use the javascript from experiment.js currently when I'm trying to use the Flask application LOCALLY**.

I suspect that maybe things will work if I push to heroku... But I need to get a local debugged solution up and running first and foremost. So i need to figure out how to correctly reference these files.

I had gotten error messages before when I used `src=` and when I had variants of the url's prefix. But now, nothing happens when I get to the webpage that's supposed to load `experiment.js`. `experiment.js` uses a javascript framework called JsPsych that basically works like a static application -- no redirects occur from jspsych. You have to create an html template for flask's sake, but all you have to do for that template is include the reference to the `experiment.js` file.

Since `experiment.js` just isn't loading yet, and since there's no other html on that template because all of it is within `experiment.js`, nothing happens.

I have my environmental variables set:

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=jhdfshfjskdhfj
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=jlsjfklksfjlfh
```

I'm not sure about what permissions settings I need on s3. For my bucket, I have

```
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new access control lists (ACLs) -- Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through any access control lists (ACLs)-- Off
Block public access to buckets and objects granted through new public bucket or access point policies -- On
Block public and cross-account access to buckets and objects through any public bucket or access point policies -- On
```

So... what's going wrong here? I just want my javascript to load at least.

Comment: This looks like a perms issue; one question:  The javascript sounds like it certainly could be public, but does access to the images need to be restricted to particular users of your app, or are you happy to have these public also?

Comment: Try this URL format: `https://neuroethics-task.s3.amazonaws.com/experiment.js` This loads.

Comment: So `<script src="https://neuroethics-task.s3.amazonaws.com/experiment.js"></script>` finally worked! thank you so much

Comment: I also did change the permissions so that none of the boxes were checked - so I unblocked the last two block statements in my original post

Comment: whoa.... Wait. This actually stopped working? Now I get "status 403 (forbidden)" error messages in my console. Again, I had `<script src="https://neuroethics-task.s3.amazonaws.com/experiment.js"></script>`. It was working but... no longer

Comment: And now trying to go to "https://neuroethics-task.s3.amazonaws.com/experiment.js" gives a blank page... @v25 I've never seen something work and then not work before...

Comment: @v25 FALSE ALARM. I had to click "make public" again on amazon s3 when I updated/reuploaded this javascript file. it's back up and running now.

Comment: hehe :D glad you got it working!